# PDF to Base64 on Ionic 3 app for Android and iOS platforms

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I use [Scan bot Cordova plugin](https://scanbotsdk.github.io/documentation/cordova/#module_ScanbotSdk.createPdf) to generate `pdf` using `png`. But my API requires to send data as `base64` encoded. There is only 1 plugin for this on Ionic native. i.e [base64](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/). But it still in beta and seems it has a [lot of issues on iOS devices](https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ios). So any clue about how can I convert pdf into base64 on the Ionic app and it should work fine on both platforms. i.e. `Android` and `ioS`. Your experience about this subject really helps me to give an advice.

Comment: I've been using the Base64 Ionic native plugin for 3 months now in one app, and It's working fine. I'm using it to encode binary files up to 4Mo. Never had any issue either in Debug or in Release version, even if this plugin is marked as beta :)

Comment: Can you tell me about the experience with the iOS platform? @saperlipopette

Comment: No update for that after `Sep 7, 2017` and also it has a lot of issues on the iOS platform. Please share your experience with ioS and this plugin. @saperlipopette https://github.com/hazemhagrass/phonegap-base64/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ios

Comment: the app is on iOS and Android stores, and I never had any crash/error report. There are about 100/150 users who use this app daily, and the base64 feature does its job pretty well

Comment: Indeed just saw that issues with iOS were reported on the git. But the plugin seems to work on my side even with iOS 12

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I'll try that and come back again here and will let you know. @saperlipopette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great native plugin for this. That is [Native File plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/).It works really well.

```
 let base64String = await this.file.readAsDataURL(pdfFilePath, pdfFilename);
```

Comment: kindly share the complete unit code or method you used to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Below code is for iOS platform.

1. Generate the pdf data from images:

> ```
> func generatePdfData(_ images:[UIImage])->Data? {
>     let data = NSMutableData()
>
>     UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect.zero, nil)
>
>     for image in images {
>         UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: image.size.width,height: image.size.height), nil)
>         image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
>     }
>     UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
>     return data as Data
> }
> ```

2. Convert data into base64 string

> data.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)

Comment: This will not help me since I'm an Ionic developer. Not a native app dev. But hope native app dev will get benefits from this answer.